# 3NF one-to-one relationship controversy

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, 3nf

I am running into a problem with my database when trying to design it in 3NF.  A database in 3NF has the following characteristics:
-it is in 2nd normal form.
-It's tables contain only columns that are non-transitively dependent on the primary key

I have been seeing many people online claim that if you have a one to one relationship you should strongly consider analyzing why it is not just one table, yet my understanding of 3NF is just to do that.  Here is my database so far:
[image]
I have tried to create this database in 3NF but so far I am not sure if splitting up the BOOK_STATS and BOOK_DETAILS tables is done correctly.  I have analyzed it and determined that things like the file type and quality are not dependent on the book at all so I had to separate them.  Is this proper or do I need to take a stronger look at why they are being split?

Comment: The sense of "dependent" meant for NFs is "functionally dependent" which means that the subrow for the determining columns always appears with the same subrow for the determined columns. If a given book id only has one associated file type then when in the same table file_type is dependent on book_id.

Comment: Normalization to BCNF & below involves knowing all FDs. If you want to discuss normalization of a table please give the original table columns and FDs.

Comment: The problem with splitting a true one-to-one relation over multiple tables is the extra constraints required to enforce integrity and having to use transactions to comply with those restrictions.  However, the cardinality indicators in your diagram seem to indicate that rows in the BOOKS table can exist without corresponding rows in the BOOK_STATS or BOOK_DETAILS tables.  If that's true, separate tables are justified.  BTW, if each row in BOOK_STATS or BOOK_DETAILS belongs to a single book, consider using BOOK_ID as their primary key.

Comment: @reaanb Your comments are a bit odd considering that 1. A 1:1 relationship never requires decomposition. 2. If book:stat or book:details are 1:0-or-1 then there cannot have been a table normalized to give book_stats or book_details. (1:0-or-1 is not 1:1.)

Comment: @reaanb this is the case, a book can exist but the stats do no exist until someone accesses the book and the details will not always be available.  If I were to make the book_id the primary key for the stats and details table then the primary key in the books table would also be foreign.  Is that proper practice?

Comment: @Christopher BOOKS.BOOK_ID would be the referent of the FK constraints and would not be considered foreign.  This is a perfectly normal design decision IF it's appropriate to your situation.

Comment: (Adressing what reaanb did in another way:) This design uses null book_stats & book_details in book when there is no associated stats/details. Instead you could avoid those columns by having book_id be the key of stats/details. Whether a column set is a candidate/primary key & whether it is a FK are based on independent criteria. Learn what they are. PS You don't have any 1:1 relationships here between columns in different tables.

Comment: You don't give FDs so we can't give NFs for tables. You don't give an original table & its FDs so how can we possibly tell you if you "split" correctly? So again: Give the original table & its FDs. PS "[3NF] tables contain only columns that are non-transitively dependent on the primary key" No, they contain only columns that are prime or non-transitively dependent on all CKs. What does "yet my understanding of 3NF is just to do that" mean? Here a book has 1 file type & quality so those *are* dependent on book if together in a table. What do 1:1 relationships have to do with this?

Comment: Please clarify via edit, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting a table into more than one table with the same primary key neither violates any normal form, nor does it heal potential violations. This can easily be made plausible by regarding the steps necessary for normalizing a not yet normalized table: All these methods introduce tables with a primary key different from that of the original table. So introducing a table with the same primary key can't be a normalization step.

I belong to the fraction claiming that 1-1 relationships should be considered to be merged to one table, unless there are strong semantic or physical reasons to separate them. However, the following questions might be asked about your `book_details` table:

- The notion of "book" can mean two things: A logical entity, i.e. authors, title, content, or the physical instance. The same distinction holds for books contained in files, as your model indicates. Orwell's 1984 might be present in more than one file, a PDF in good quality, and an epub in mediocre quality, having different file sizes. Or a large book might be split in more than one file. I don't know the purpose of your model and application, but I would try to cover real-world phenomena like this, as adding them later will affect large parts of the application and be costly. So I could imagine to transform your `book_detail` table to a `media` table having a 1:n or even m:n relationship to the book.
- Are there pre-defined value ranges for `file_quality` and `file_type`, like "excellent, good, mediocre, bad", "pdf, epub, txt, ..."? In that case, these values should be part of another table, and your `book` or `book_detail` would just contain the id in that table as foreign key.

Comment: Normalization can introduce a table with the same candidate key as the original. But not all the introduced tables will. Re bullet 2: That design change is not an example of normalization, which does not introduce new columns (eg an id).

Comment: @TAM you are actually right I apologize. In the details table, a book can be split into multiple files each with their own size making the relation 1:m so that takes care of the details table 1:1 and just leaves the stats table.

Comment: @Christopher 1:0/1 relationships are not poor practice.

Comment: @Christopher What do you mean there are different book_ids when details differ yet there can be duplicate records?

Comment: @Christopher Please see my other comments on this page: 1. Normalization theory doesn't address tables with nulls. Your design *does not arise from normalizing another design* because the 1:0s mean there cannot have been an undecomposed table with book_id & either of the others for the case of there being no associated stats/details. 2. When book_stats & book_details are in the same table as book_id & can't be null then they *are* functionally dependent on it. 3. Normalization does not involve new column names. 4. We can't tell whether *these* tables are in 3NF without having the FDs.